# How to fully install linux on a USB flash drive

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb

i need to install linux (Ubuntu) on a flash drive, i need it for installing the OS on my pandaboard ES.
I want to make a full installation (not the live cd one)

I've tried installing it from a cd to the flash drive (8gb) setting 7gb with ext4 for the system (sdc1) and the rest for swap (sdc2) and i've set sdc as boot

The installation went ok but when i booted from usb drive a black screen appeared and nothing was happening

Comment: I have done this and i regretted my decision later on. Can you elaborate on why you want to do that? Installing Ubuntu on usb flash is like any installation. The reason I say don't do that is becuase usb interface is a bottle neck. They are so slow that OS will slow to a crawl , making it unusable. Any write operation are worst affected. Like `apt-get upgrade` .

Comment: I need it to install android on my pandaboard, i don't want to make a full installation on my hdd.
I would use it only when i have to update my pandaboard, so even if it's slow i don't mind as i would use it very rarely

Comment: Do you have to use Ubuntu to do this, for example, puppy Linux is a much better choice for USB installs.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/), it is THE resource for linux on pendrives.